# NGINX: X-Content-Type-Options nosniff results in wrong resource/MIME-types

Tags: javascript, angular, security, nginx, mime-types

I get errors like:

```
10:24:45.375 localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
10:24:45.390 localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost/polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
10:24:45.391 localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost/main.4946ee69e21757a0ea38.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
10:24:50.815 localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost/styles.34c57ab7888ec1573f9c.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

after setting X-Content-Type-Options to nosniff in NGINX. I am building Angular (version 6.0.3) like

```
"ng build --prod --configuration=production --subresource-integrity"
```

And the output index.html looks like:

```
...
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js" integrity="sha384-v4rB9z5qXuO6U644SALSrNM0l0wvQcniOlRg9Lk3fA3ljnzuAPpETTdOPFjvxVhc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js" integrity="sha384-ducWBZzn39ArKnKYY70ngb3N7WZhfaMAfPG/AMC1XZcbUcvz0GmT3ymoBXA7KrUt" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.d28db731850ff9163bb0.js" integrity="sha384-ewBSByvIwZ3px9WtXD5S4GxV8AtRmjlqDY4RS81hPo3D6j1NU3EcB/Hd7zw7KA+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></body>
```

Why is the specified type "text/javascript" instead of "application/javascript"? And is this mismatch causing the error or something else? Then why does Chrome report `because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable`, detecting a completely different MIME-type than specified?

BTW I am testing this on localhost with self-signed certs, but theoretically this should not be relevant (?)

Comment: This is not about what you specify via the `type` attribute on the script element inside your HTML, this is about the `Content-Type` header your server delivers these resources with.

Comment: @CBroe Is it not both? I thought `X-Content-Type-Options nosniff` tells the browser to execute only those resources that are marked with `application/javascript` or another script-type and not try to determine whether a resource like an `<img href="...">` might be a script and execute it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options: _“Note: nosniff only applies to "script" and "style" types. Also applying nosniff to images turned out to be incompatible with existing web sites.”_

Comment: @CBroe even if it's not about images, the same page you linked says it's a good practice to set the header. Then why are my <script>-tags with type="text/javascript" blocked? If this is not about type (which you said), then what is it about? How do you conform the code to the header?

Comment: _“Then why are my <script>-tags with type="text/javascript" blocked?”_ - because your server claims the referred resources are something else!

Comment: @CBroe isn't it the browser that claims that? And why does it do it?

Comment: You know what a Content-Type response header is, right? If not, please go read up on that first. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Comment: @CBroe ok now I get it, thank you. It looks like it might have something to do with gzip-encoding, which I have configured too: https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg/issues/2186069

Answer (score 2):

When you set X-Content-Type-Options to nosniff you also have to set the allowed types in NGINX. In order to do that you just need to reference their file:

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    # ...
}
```